# Expose data from HIVE and Hbase as a REST API - Hadoop Datalake - Python Pyspark

Tags: python-3.x, scala, apache-spark-sql, flask-restful

I am trying to query a Hive and HBase DB and expose that data as REST API in JSON format using Python/Scala. How do I go about this? Any roadmap to achieve this implementation?

Any help would be appreciated .